# urllib2.URLError, testing python function.

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm testing my python function

```
def page_data(url):
    try:
        data = urlopen(url)
    except urllib2.URLError:
        raise urllib2.URLError('bad url %s' % url)
```

When i pass the url 'http://faleeeeee.ru' is raisees exception(as needed)
But when I run my unittest for this

```
self.assertRaises(page_data('http://faleeeeee.ru'), urllib2.URLError)
```

the test fails. Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Docu -> http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises

```python
self.assertRaises(urllib2.URLError, page_data, 'http://faleeeeee.ru')
```

OR - context manager with python 2.7 and upwards.

```python
with self.assertRaises(urllib2.URLError):
    page_data('http://faleeeeee.ru')
```